# Change only footer to full width?

Tags: html, css, footer, blogger

I was wondering is there a way to stretch only the footer in blogger simple template to full width, without affecting other blog elements? I read the similar topics, but they were about wordpress or changing the other elements, too, and mine is blogger platform. I tried with changing this code:

```
.content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner {min-width: auto; max-width: auto; _width: $(content.width);}
```

and I did stretched the footer, but also the other blog elements. So, is there a way to leave other elements unaffected and manipulate only with footer element?

My blog's URL is: http://fashionsanja.blogspot.rs

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use position:fixed. It absolutely positions elements in the browser window. Additionally, by setting left and right it will span the entire width of the browser window. Based on your site, the following worked in dev tools:

```
#KBD {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your efforts to help me, I really appreciate it, but that didn't work for me, somehow it just 'ate' my footer

Comment: Yes, I did what you wrote (in the #KBD code above), I don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: No problem. Just position your footer tag at the same level as your div with class="content-outer". In short, position it just under the div with class="content", and next to div with content-outer.